# Debian 3.1 (Sarge) init.d boot order

Tags: debian, boot, init.d

I am using a [TS-7800 single board computer](http://www.embeddedarm.com/products/board-detail.php?product=ts-7800) from Technologic Systems that ships with Debian 3.1 (Sarge).  I have updated it to Squeeze, but due to various driver issues I have been forced to roll back to Sarge.  I am attempting to configure the various drivers and configurations needed for my application services before they start. Ideally I would call one init.d script that contains the drivers / configurations then call the other init.d scripts (one for each process).

I am left scratching my head on how to guarantee the boot sequence.  I know in later versions of Debian I could use the [LSB header](http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts/DependencyBasedBoot) to achieve this; but **is there anything comparable to the LSB header in Sarge?**

Answer (score 0):

It's plain System V init scripts. So no dependencies by default, you can only plan the order of starting and in which run levels.